# Want to get dates from this data where AS_code changed first and also before that

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions

In this sample data, want to get date where AS_code changed AS0003 to AS0001 and also where AS0004 to AS0003(Duplicacy is also the issue, AS0003 comes twice). Basically, required help in query which can return date where AS_code change at first and previous (before that).

Can't use values in a query, dependent on columns only. I have only one table from which I have to return those values only. Eg. select eccode, ascode, max(date) from tablex a INNER JOIN tablex y on a.eccode=b.eccode and a.ascode<>b.ascode (I tried this).

```
EC_Code AS_Cde  Effective Date
EC00001 AS0001  9/30/2019
EC00001 AS0001  10/1/2019
EC00001 AS0001  10/2/2019
EC00001 AS0001  10/3/2019
EC00001 AS0001  10/4/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/19/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/20/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/21/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/22/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/23/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/24/2019
EC00001 AS0003  10/25/2019
EC00001 AS0004  12/5/2019
EC00001 AS0004  12/6/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/7/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/8/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/9/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/10/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/11/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/12/2019
EC00001 AS0003  12/13/2019
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/2029983)

Comment: How are you identifying which AS0003 records were changed to AS0001? I see no way to logically conclude that change.

Comment: If the matter is that urgent, shouldn't you be looking to hire a consultant on short  notice? Telling us it's urgent won't endear us to help you; if the problem is that bad you shouldn't be relying on [so].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(as_code) over(order by effective_date) lag_as_code
    from mytable t
) t
where (lag_as_code = 'AS0003' and code = 'AS0001')
   or (lag_as_code = 'AS0004' and code = 'AS0003')
```

Basically this identifies the transition from `'AS0003'` to `'AS0001'` and from `'AS0004'` to `'AS0003'`, and brings the rows when the new code is reached.

Comment: Can't use values in a query, dependent on columns only. I have only one table from which i have to return those values only. Eg. select eccode,ascode,max(date) from tablex  a INNER JOIN tablex y on a.eccode=b.eccode and a.ascode<>b.ascode(I tried this)